# How to write OOBtree indexing on disk?

Tags: python, b-tree, inverted-index

I have large information to index and create posting List for retrieval later, I  searched and understood that `BTree Data structure` is suitable to store large data mapping on disk.

In The python Libraries I found Btree 4.08 and read the Document, I used `OOBTree module` in my code, insert data to `OOBtree` but I don't know which part of this tree must be stored on disk, or how to store?

Here is link for [BTree Python Document](http://pythonhosted.org/BTrees/):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider [ZODB](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/index.html), and its [BTree](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/documentation/guide/modules.html#btrees-package) module.  ZODB is an object database, providing an efficient way to read and write Python objects and structures to disk.